# Вызов метода С# с помощью PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

Как вызвать метод C# и указать, какие должны быть входные данные?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46160170/5752652

Comment: Непонятно. В каком смысле метод C#? Вы имеете в виду, (скомпилированный) метод .NET-сборки?

Comment: @VladD у меня в файле .cs описаны классы и их методы. Компилируется ведь весь проект, или можно компилировать отдельные методы?

Comment: @kosmo_tony: Ну то есть у вас есть скомпилированая DLL, да?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как указано в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46160170/276994), нужно использовать `Add-Type`.

```
Add-Type -Path тут-путь-к-вашей.dll
```

После этого можно использовать типы из неё. Например, для такого класса

```
public class Library
{
    public string GetHello() { return "hello world"; }
}
```

работает код

```
(New-Object TestNamespace.Library).GetHello()
```

---

Если у вас код не скомпилирован, вы можете добавить его и из исходника!

```
PS D:\Test> Add-Type -Path .\Library.cs
PS D:\Test> (New-Object TestNamespace.Library).GetHello()
hello world
```